# How to upload HD video to YouTube using unlimited 4G LTE on iPhone?

Tags: youtube

I have unlimited 4G LTE with Sprint so I should be able to upload to YouTube using it, but YouTube can only allow SD (Standard Definition) upload. The HD upload says, "Requires WiFi".  (this was done by going to Photos app, and then using Share to YouTube).

But my WiFi will be slower... and sometimes I don't have WiFi if I am outside... so is there a way to upload it using the unlimited 4G LTE?

Answer (score 1):

If your device is jailbroken, you can use 3G Unrestrictor, which will fake apps into thinking you are connected to a Wi-Fi network, thus enabling the higher quality upload.

- http://cydia.saurik.com/package/com.kstreich-dev.3gunrestrictor5/

Comment: is it only something restricted by YouTube? For example, the YouTube app can allow it (or just ask each time before uploading, something like "Warning: this will upload a large amount of data. Confirm uploading with Cellular Data traffic?"

Comment: @太極者無極而生 Yes, it's YouTube's restriction. Doesn't make sense not to allow disabling it, but there it is. :/